# Remove specific subdirectory in unix

Tags: linux, find

I need to remove specific type of sub directories  from  sub directory in unix enviroment.
It means, In main directory I have 1000 sub directory. Each sub directory contain work folder along with files which need to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `find` maybe? If your sub-directories are empty, this will work:

```
find . -name "a" -type d | xargs rmdir
```

if you sub directories are no empty, this will work:

```
find . -name "a" -type d | xargs rm -Rf
```

I have created:

```
d@reference:~/tmp/TT$ tree
    .
    ├── a
    └── b
        └── a

3 directories, 0 files
```

Then I want to remove all subdirectories called `a`:

```
d@reference:~/tmp/TT$ find . -name "a" -type d | xargs rmdir
```

What remains:

```
d@reference:~/tmp/TT$ tree
.
└── b

1 directory, 0 files
```